# keras TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, keras

I imported the dataset with the code below.

```
dataset_csv = np.loadtxt('/home/user/Downloads/dataset.csv', delimiter=',')


x_train=dataset_csv[:3000000,0:3]
y_train=dataset_csv[:3000000,3]
x_test=dataset_csv[3000000:,0:3]
y_test=dataset_csv[3000000:,3]
```

The total data set is 3193739.

Each dataset has the following form.
(value1 ,value2,value3, class)

I tried to insert data by setting the input layer as follows.

```
model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=3, activation='relu'))
```

However, the following error occurred.

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I'm wondering why you can not read integer types and how you can make a dataset readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with reading of the data, it is with the input_shape parameter in the Dense Class.

```
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=3, activation='relu'))
```

input shape should be a tuple. so, modify it to the following

```
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'))
```